# bash: redirect output of "find -exec" into a file without newlines; -- temporarily removing symlinks when sharing directory in VirtualBox

Tags: bash, find, virtualbox, symlink

Sometimes, I use VirtualBox with a Windows guest system under a Linux Mint host system, with a shared directory `~/_D` corresponding to my `D:\`-drive in Windows.  However, there are many symbolic links to directories below `~/_D`, some of which are even circular, which causes some Windows processes not to work as I need.

Therefore I am working on a bash script that temporarily removes all symlinks below `~/_D` and at the same time creates another script that can restore those symlinks later when I am done with my work on Windows.

However, I am struggling with writing the output of the `find ... -exec readlink {} \;` command into a file without newlines.  My script currently goes like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

cd ~/_D

echo "# restores all symlinks deleted by ~/bin/symlink.remove" > symlinks.restore
echo >> symlinks.restore

find . -type l -exec readlink {} \; -print -exec echo "" \; -exec rm {} \; >> symlinks.restore

echo >> symlinks.restore
echo "# run emacs command sd-restore-symlinks on this file" >> symlinks.restore

chmod u+x symlinks.restore

echo to restore symlinks, run emacs command sd-restore-symlinks on ~/_D/symlinks.restore
echo then run ~/_D/symlinks.restore
```

Instead of awkwardly using an emacs search-and-replace-function just for rearranging the output for each symlink from two lines, separated by an empty line, into one line, resulting in lines such as `ln -s "../.Events.OLD" "./Events/Events.OLD"` (mind the quotes to avoid havoc with possible spaces in filenames), I would love to generate the output file `symlinks.restore` directly from my bash script.

However, using hacks like: `find -type l -exec echo -n $(readlink {}) \;`  does not work, probably because`{}` is not accessible as alias for the current file within `$()`, also not when quoted `\{\}`.

I guess that some smart combination of `-printf` or `-print0` actions of `find`, and/or perhaps `sed`, can do the trick, but this goes beyond what I can achieve.

Also, perhaps there are already tools to temporarily remove and then restore all symlinks below a certain directory?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

With `-printf` something like.

```
find . -type l -printf 'ln -s "%p" "%l"\n' > symlinks.restore
```

---

It has limitations and it is not bullet proof, which was mentioned by [M. Nejat Aydin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13809001/m-nejat-aydin)

Comment: This won't work if a symbolic link or its target contains white space.

Comment: This time, it won't work if a symbolic link or its target contains a `"` character in its name.

Comment: Also, from security perspective, this method is vulnerable. A malicious user could create a symbolic link named `$(malicious_command)` and the `malicious_command` would be executed when the restore script is run.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, except that %p and %l need to be exchanged, and quotes added around them.

Comment: I understand the possible attack. Luckily, I do not have any filename with a "-character, so that problem does not arise.

Comment: @Tsepati A filename containing `"` character isn't related to the security problem, but a filename in with the pattern `$(...)` is. A malicious program might create such a file.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `find` command to create restore script:

```
find . -type l -exec bash -c '
    for symlnk; do
        printf "ln -s %q %q\n" "$(readlink "$symlnk")" "$symlnk"
    done' _ {} + > symlinks.restore
```

The restore script (symlinks.restore) must be run (or `source`d) from the same directory as the `find` command is run.

Comment: Thanks!  This taught me a lot.
However, if there are spaces in filenames, this solution generates broken symlinks with backslashes in the link target.

Comment: @Tsepati backslashes shouldn't break anything if you're using the output as an executable bash script. `"file with spaces"` and `file\ with\ spaces` are equivalent to the bash parser, the quotes and backslashes are both processed and removed in the same parsing step.

Comment: Yes, in principle it *should* work.
Still, using the find command verbatim as suggested by M. Nejat Aydin, I got links that point to non-existent files with literal backslashes in their names. 
I tried using quotes around %p and %l.

Comment: @Tsepati Could you please show an example line from the output that exhibits the behaviour you described? I'm on the mobile phone and cannot test right now.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin, I had already deleted that version of the script. I tried it again and now could indeed not reproduce the error -- probably my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both, M. Nejat Aydin and Jetchisel.

The latter solution worked best for me, with some adjustments (quotes, changed order of parameters `%p` and `%l`, and added `rm` command).

My script now reads:

```
#! /bin/bash

cd ~/_D

printf "#! /bin/bash\n\n# restores all symlinks deleted by ~/bin/symlink.remove\n# has to be executed in _D\n\n" > symlinks.restore

find . -type l -printf 'ln -s "%l" "%p"\n' -exec rm {} \; >> symlinks.restore

chmod u+x symlinks.restore
```

This works fine, even with spaces in filenames.

Differently from my earlier comments, the other solution also works without producing literal backslashes in the link targets; the relevant command I now successfully used is

```
find . -type l -exec bash -c '
    for symlnk; do
        printf "ln -s \"%q\" \"%q\"\n" "$(readlink "$symlnk")" "$symlnk"
    rm $symlnk
    done' _ {} + >> symlinks.restore
```

Thanks again to all who responded.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Just asking because the `%l` is the symlink and the `%p` is the real path and file.

Comment: yes, in the ```ln -s``` command the first argument is the target and the second the link to be created.

Comment: Yes, but `'ln -s "%l" "%p"\n'` means `ln -s link target` yes?

Comment: no, as I said, the first argument is the target, so it is ```ln -s target link```